# Unable to get vscode to stop at a conditional breakpoint in a C++ debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSC on a Mac to work on a C++ project running on a Linux VM using gcc & gdb. Everything works great, but I can't get conditional breakpoints to work. If I set a breakpoint, execution will stop there every time. But if I make the breakpoint conditional on an expression, execution never steps.

The VSC debugging instructions don't provide an example, so maybe I'm entering the conditions incorrectly.

I want the program to stop at the loop when i == 2. The expression I tried but didn't work:

`(i == 2)`

Moreover, When I set a hit-count condition, execution stops the next time the breakpoint is reached, so that doesn't seem to work as expected, either.

Comment: Are you definitely using gsb and not lldb?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, I used gdb.

Comment: Conditional breakpoints are slow as ass anyways. Just put an if check in the code and place a non conditional bp in the if code.